# Amazon EC2 reserved instances

Tags: amazon-ec2

I maintain alot of amazon instances of different types (medium, micro, small) etc. However, Some instances I want to reserve for a few years. But,

From what I've read everywhere :

```
Reserved instances are a billing feature, not a technical feature.
```

So if I reserve a micro instance and later I convert that instance from micro to large, will the reserved instance slot be taken up by the next micro instance I have in my ec2 instances list (provided they are in the same AZ) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is basically as you say. When you are billed Amazon first checks for reserved instances and only if you are out of those, normal rates apply.

[See here for reference](http://aws.amazon.com/en/ec2/reserved-instances/):

"Easy to Use: Reserved Instances are easy to use and require no change to how you use EC2. When computing your bill, our system will automatically apply Reserved Instance rates first to minimize your costs. An instance hour will only be charged at the On-Demand rate when your total quantity of instances running that hour exceeds the number of applicable Reserved Instances you own."

So technically there is no difference between an reserved instance and a non-reserved one.

Answer (score 2):

It will be taken by any instance that matches the reservation. A reservation is not tied to a specific instance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

I like to call it the trickle down.  Where the reserved instance will trickle down to the next unreserved instance that matches the same instance size.

Note: One nice feature is the ability to reorganize your instances to different sizes within the same instance type.  For example, you have 5 m1.xlarge instances, you can split them into 40 m1.small instaces and vice versa.  Unfortunately, you can't go between m1, t1, c1, c3, etc.